# SPService - GetItemList - How can I populate custom ListItems?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript

I have a custom SharePoint list and want to get all items (title, kpi, delta) populate in a html site - I am using SPService with getitemlist.

[image]

For Title its working fine, but for kpi and delta the result is always 'undefined' - What I have to do, to retrieve the right value ?

[image]

Comment: the internal names are kpi and delta correct? also there is a space in the CAMLViewFields there that could be causing an issue, it could be seeing it as malformed CAML and thus not returning the field you are asking for leading to the undefined error. everything else looks good.

Comment: the internal names were different - that was the case why the values didn't showed. thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

found the solution today - the custom list items have an other attribute description, as i entered.

to find out the attribute description of list items, you can open the list, view source and search your list - there you will find the attribute description of each item.

With that solution I could populate all my items.